# How to get all subcategories ids of specific category id in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get all subcategories ids of specific category id in magento2

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get all child category id of any particular category.

```
<?php
    $categoryId = 1; //Category ID
    $storeId = 1; //Store ID
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryRepository = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository");
    $category = $categoryRepository->get($categoryId,$storeId);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($category->getChildrenCategories()->getAllIds());echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Is above solution helpful to you ?